# exception when printing accents on linux

Tags: python, linux, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I have wrote a very basic python3.5 script which display a message in the console with print function.

This script works great on my personal computer.

I've uploaded to a linux computer and i get this exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe8' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I do not understand why it works on my computer and not on the target computer.

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

Here is my code:

```
print('hello world é è")
```

Comment: Can you show us your script?

Comment: see my edit, i have add the code

Comment: It works for me in python3.7, is that the entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locale in your Linux environment only supports ASCII.  Consequently, you get an error when trying to print non-ASCII characters.

The best *workaround* for this is to set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) variable to UTF-8, or set the [PYTHONUTF8](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUTF8) environment variable to '1'.  For example

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python myprogram.py
```

The best *solution* is to set a locale that supports UTF-8.  This can be done through the operating system's regional setting menu or by changing the relevant config files (the files may vary between distros).  UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII so the change should not cause any problems (but back up critical data anyway).

It's also possible to strip non-ASCII characters from the string before printing, but this approach loses information.  Non-ASCII characters may be removed completely by ignoring [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) errors:

```
>>> s = 'hello world é è'
>>> print(s.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode())
hello world
```

or the [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) function can be used to try to obtain an equivalent  ASCII character, if the unicode character can be decomposed to an ASCII character and an accent.

```
>>> print(ud.normalize('NFD', s).encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode())
hello world e e
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of your file

Comment: You should use comment box for this kind of info

Answer (score 0):

try this

---

```
a="hello world é è".encode("iso-8859-15")
print(a.decode("iso-8859-15"))
```